# ClassNotFoundException but class in the same folder

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I really don't get it. I just created a more-simply-is-not-possible java project. Only two classes, in the same folder. It is a regular project with no fancy configuration on Eclipse.

Main class :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        MyClass var;
        try{
            var = new MyClass(); //throws classNotFoundException
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The other class :

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(){
    }
}
```

First, the classNotFoundException (which is, in this provect, improbable. In addition to that, the try/catch block does not catch anything. I still got the stackTrace by using the eclipse debugging tool:

```
Main (1) [Java Application] 
    Main at localhost:52311 
        Thread [main] (Suspended)   
            owns: Object  (id=27)   
            owns: Object  (id=28)   
            ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286   
            ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available 
            ClassNotFoundException(ReflectiveOperationException).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available  
            ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available   
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
            Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
            Main.main(String[]) line: 9
```

I tried to clean the project and restart eclipse, but it does not help. Two days ago everything worked fine, I did not change anything. What is happening ?

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: I haven't made a simple project like this in forever.  Are they in the same package?  They might need to be.

Comment: @RobertBeltran The user has already mentioned they are in the same folder

Comment: a folder and a package are different

Comment: Are you exporting this as a jar file when you run it, or just running it with the play button in eclipse?

Comment: Check to see if both class files are being generated as a starting point

Comment: I'm not sure but he seems to have some non-default/strange eclipse set-up as the exception clearly states that a URLClassLoader is invoked which for a simple project should not happen!

Comment: Isnt the system class loader a URL class loader? It does load classes based on a path after all.

Comment: I was stuck on this problem for an hour, but after I drank a cup of milk, I triedagain, it did not work, then put the second class in an other package which I include in the main class, it did not work, then move back in the same folder and it worked again. I already did that before but now it is working for no reason. Should I delete my post ? PS: everytime, I ran it by right-click on the project > run as > java application

Comment: @Vulpo Eclipse is very flaky. I believe you end up saving more time just re-installing it every time it craps out!